# Mostrar elementos de un archivo json en javascrip

Tags: javascript, json

Empecé por hacer una estadística con un archivo `json` y me dió el siguiente error:

> Error"covid.js:17 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'state')

```
>at HTMLButtonElement.clickBoton (covid.js:17:44)"
```

El archivo tiene la siguiente estructura:

```
{
    "date":20200501,
    "state":"CA",
    "positive":50442,
    "probableCases":null,
    ...
}
```

Llevo días tratando de acceder a los demás elementos, pero me dice que no los puede leer.

Los dos elementos que quiero mostrar son `date` y `state` para poder filtrarlos con esos criterios.

Use también una variable global en la consola `devtools` y no me muestra los demás elementos algo así:

`temp1.date` después me muestra la fecha abajo y la escribo entre corchetes y después me dice *undefined*. Después ya no puedo agregar otro elemento como "state"

Les voy agradecer profundamente el que me ayuden a entender la logica de la carga de los elementos de un json.

Atte

Felix Del Rio

```js
window.onload = iniciar;

function iniciar() {
let boton = document.getElementById("btnCargar");
boton.addEventListener("click", clickBoton);
}

async function cargarUrl(url) {
    let response = await fetch(url);
    return response.json();
}

async function clickBoton() {
    let json = await cargarUrl('https://api.covidtracking.com/v1/states/ca/20200501.json')
    console.log(json);

    let estadisticas = json.date[20200501].state["CA"];
    console.log(estadisticas);


}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Estadisticas Covid</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div>
        <h1>Estadisticas del Covid-19</h1>

        <b>Fecha</b> <input  id="InpFecha" type="date" /><br/>
        <b>País</b>  
        <select id="SelSte">
            <option value="ca">California</option>
            <option value="tx">Texas</option>
        </select> <br />
        <button id="btnCargar">Cargar Estadisticas</button>
    </div>

    <script src="covid.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Te retorna un objeto con propiedades. Para acceder a la propiedad **date** haces `json.date` y para **state** `json.state`, nada mas y así de simple

Comment: Buenasce tardes: Yessef agradezco tu apoyo realice el siguente cambio en codigo, por lo sugerido asi:    let estadisticas = json.date[20200501].json.state["CA"]; y medio este error "covid.js:17 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'json')
    at HTMLButtonElement.clickBoton (covid.js:17:44)"

Answer (score 0):

Tu código funciona hasta esta parte

```
async function clickBoton() {
    let json = await cargarUrl('https://api.covidtracking.com/v1/states/ca/20200501.json')
    console.log(json);

    let estadisticas = json.date[20200501].state["CA"]; //esto está mal
    console.log(estadisticas);
}
```

Tu tienes un JSON que te retorna un objeto con varias propiedades en su interior, para acceder a dichas propiedades usas el operador punto `.` es decir `objeto.propiedad`

Por lo que para acceder a las propiedades `date` y `state` debes hacer lo siguiente:

```
async function clickBoton() {
   //cambie el nombre de json a respuesta, porque en este punto tienes un objeto NO un json 
   let respuesta = await cargarUrl('https://api.covidtracking.com/v1/states/ca/20200501.json')
 

    let estado = respuesta.state;
    let date = respuesta.date;
    console.log(estado,date);
}
```

Comment: Realice lo sugerido @Yussef, con éxito, continuo con la otra parte de mi proyecto, estaré pendiente para contestar con tu respuesta a otros nuevos compañeros que tengan el mismo error, excelente dia!!

Comment: @FelixDelRioSandoval Que bueno haber podido ayudarte, recuerda marcar la respuesta como aceptada si así te parece. Saludos y suerte en tu proyecto